# SQL - Relation between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm making a databse of medications, that has three main tables: Medications, ActiveIngredients and a third table for linking between medications and active ingredients, say MedicationsActiveIngredients.
Table Medications like this

MedicationID -- MedicationName

M1 -- Medication # 1

M2 -- Medication # 2

M3 -- Medication # 3

and so on

Table ActiveIngredients like this

ACtiveIngredientID -- ActiveIngredientName

AI1 - Active Ingredient # 1

AI2 - Active Ingredient # 2

AI3 - Active Ingredient # 3

and so on

Table MedicationsActiveIngredients looks like this

MedicationID -- ActiveIngredientID

and if Medication # 1 has two active ingredients; Active Ingredient 1 and Active Ingredient 2, I add two rows to the third table like this

M1 -- AI1

M1 -- AI2

if I want to get a list of a mediaction's active ingredients, I use this SQL query

```
SELECT ActiveIngredients.ActiveIngredientName
FROM ActiveIngredients, MedicationsActiveIngredients
WHERE ActiveIngredients.ActiveIngredientID = MedicationsActiveIngredients.ActiveIngredientID
AND MedicationsActiveIngredients.MedicationID = 'M1'
```

the questions are:

1- is my structure well formed?, or it can be formulated in a better way?

2- how can i get a list of medications that have the combination of active ingredients (let's say medications that have Active ingredient # 1 + Active ingredient # 2?

3- how can i get list of medications that have a similar composition (having one more or less active ingredient) to another medication?

I'm using both MSSQL (in a windows forms app) and MySQL (in a website)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc etc? Tag your question.

Comment: I'm on mobile now, so it's hard to write a query, but I can answer your first question. Yes, it's a good design for your needs

Comment: That's three questions. First one is off topic, but the answer is yes your design is good. Third question is strange, I'd be pretty worried if some one said this one's nearly the same except it has digitalin in it instead of ascorbic acid...

Comment: Actually, I have BSC in pharmaceutical sciences, so you are in my area :) - let's say a user wanna know the medications that have similar composition to Atacand (candesartan) - that will be Atacand plus (candesartan + HCTZ), but it has an additional active ingredient ,, the same applies to Panadol and Panadol Extra ,,, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modern join syntax

```
 SELECT ActiveIngredients.ActiveIngredientName
 FROM ActiveIngredients, 
      inner join MedicationsActiveIngredients
           ON ActiveIngredients.ActiveIngredientID = MedicationsActiveIngredients.ActiveIngredientID
      WHERE MedicationsActiveIngredients.MedicationID = 'M1'
```

To find formulations with common ingredients

```
select MedicationID
from MedicationsActiveIngredients 
where ActiveIngredientID in (2,3) 
group by MedicationID
having COUNT(distinct ActiveIngredientID) = 2 -- number of ingredients
```

To find similar formulations in SQL Server, you can do this.

```
;with cte as 
    (   select *, COUNT(ActiveIngredientID) over (partition by MedicationID) ic from MedicationsActiveIngredients)
select t1.MedicationID, t2.MedicationID
from cte t1
    inner join cte t2
        on t1.ActiveIngredientID = t2.ActiveIngredientID
        and t1.MedicationID<>t2.MedicationID
group by t1.MedicationID, t2.MedicationID, t1.ic, t2.ic
having ABS(t1.ic-count(*))<=1 and ABS(t2.ic-COUNT(*))<=1
order by t1.MedicationID, t2.MedicationID
```

MySQL lacks the necessary constructs, so it will be more complex.

Comment: thanks, you're brilliant. But, in the 2nd query, I think if there is a medication having active ingredient #2 + active ingredient #3 + Other ingredients (that will be a different formulation), it will appear also in the result - how to make a query that shows medications from having only active ingredients #2 and #3

Comment: @MegamindSaiko In that case, it's effectively the same as query 3, changing the count difference from 1 to 0.